# restangular doesnt return from node-restful API

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, rest, restangular

I am really stuck with this REST API restangular config for my MEAN web application. So I have created the express server with node-restful API and can use POSTMAN to perform CRUD operations and my data is being saved to a MongoDB via Mongoose.

The client side application is a yeoman bootstrap using grunt and I can see hardcoded data in scope if I define it as per below in the controller, however when I attempt to `GetList()` with Restangular I am having the issue I can see posted previously with returning data from the API Restangular setbaseURL http://localhost:8080/horse.

I understand `getList` doesn't return data, the factory service is doing this, but I have it set like the examples online and cannot get it to return all records in the MongoDB to the angular view.  Also tried `ng-resource` and I cannot understand why I can't add data from the API to scope.

Code below returns `Horsename` to `"ngview"` fine from `HorseCtrl` using `<td>horse in horses</td> table`

```
angular.module('HorseApp')
  .controller('HorseCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.horses = [
       {
       horseName: 'MAYKBE DIVA'
       }
    ];

  });
```

below wont return data and my factory is set in app.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('HorseApp', ['restangular']);

app.controller('HorseCtrl', function($scope, Restangular) {
$scope.horses = Restangular.all('horses').getList().$object;
        });
```

**app.js**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('HorseApp', [
    'ngRoute'
    'restangular'
  ])
  .config(function ($routeProvider, RestangularProvider) {
    RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('http://localhost:8081/horse');
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: '/views/index.html',
        controller: 'HorsesCtrl'
      });
  })
.factory('HorseRestangular', function(Restangular) {
  return Restangular.withConfig(function(RestangularConfigurer) {
    RestangularConfigurer.setRestangularFields({
      id: '_id' 
    });
  });
})
.factory('Horse', function(HorseRestangular) {
  return HorseRestangular.service('horse');
})
```

I have added the src to index.html as per below, please help :)

```
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
     <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
 <script src="bower_components/angular-ui-select/dist/select.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
   <script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
   <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/restanuglar/dist/restangular.js"></script>
```

Comment: so after 12 hours ,  i used $resource('http://localhost:8081/horse/ to show data on my view : )  maybe ill have restangular working soon but still would like some help , cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you are globally setting the base url for Restangular to http://localhost:8081/horse, and in your HorseCtrl you are asking Restangular to access the horses endpoint and get the list. This will effectively access the data at http://localhost:8081/horse/horses. I am not sure if this is the intended path.

Your HorseRestangular and Horse factory are not being used. If you were to change the Restangular injection of the controller to Horse, it would access http://localhost:8081/horse/horse, and have the id available through the _id property. You don't necessarily need all of the services unless you will be communicating with more than one API through restangular. To simplify it, you can do this:

```
angular.module('HorseApp', ['restangular'])
.config(function ($routeProvider, RestangularProvider) {

    RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('http://localhost:8081');

    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: '/views/index.html',
        controller: 'HorsesCtrl'
      });
    });
})
.controller('HorseCtrl', function ($scope, Restangular) {
    $scope.horses = Restangular.all('horses').getList().$object;
});
```